# Formatting column with multiple conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json, formatting

I'm having trouble formatting the JSON for a column called **"SLA Day Counter"**. This column just counts the days between when the request was received and when it was actually handled. The request should be handled within 3 days of receipt unless it's a website review request which should be handled within 10 days. There is another column called **"Initiative"** that identifies what type of request it is. The problem is there are 4 website initiatives (Website-Full/New Review, Website-Other, Website-Business, Website-Update). I tried to convince the team to only use one but they are adamant on keeping those classifications.

Anyways, I created the following formatting rules using the simple formatting tool on SharePoint:

1. IF SLA day counter is greater than 3 AND IF Initiative does not equal to Website-Full/New Review, cell will show as red
2. IF SLA day counter is greater than 3 AND IF Initiative does not equal to Website-Other, cell will show as red
3. IF SLA day counter is greater than 3 AND IF Initiative does not equal to Website-Business, cell will show as red
4. IF SLA day counter is greater than 3 AND IF Initiative does not equal to Website-Update, cell will show as red
5. IF SLA day counter is greater than 10 AND IF Initiative is equal to Website-Full/New Review, cell will show as red
6. IF SLA day counter is greater than 10 AND IF Initiative is equal to Website-Other, cell will show as red
7. IF SLA day counter is greater than 10 AND IF Initiative is equal to Website-Business, cell will show as red
8. IF SLA day counter is greater than 10 AND IF Initiative is equal to Website-Update, cell will show as red

However, even if the Initiative is Website-Update and the SLA day counter is only at 7 days, it will still show as red. Please help! :'O

Comment: Check my answer, if SLA = 7 days and Initiative = Website-Update it shouldn't be red ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

### 1.1 Trying to understand

---

First of all we need to simplfy your business requirement into a simple set of a Logical condition to make it for the Computer to understand it :

Here, from all the condition you have mentioned, the column become **RED** only if :

[The SLA Day Counter > 3]
**AND**
Initiative != ["Website-Full","New Review", "Website-Business","Website-Other","Website-Update"]

**OR**

The SLA Day Counter > 10
**AND**
Initiative = ["Website-Full","New Review", "Website-Business","Website-Other","Website-Update"]

---

### 1.2 Solution

---

1-Create a new column "**Calculated Column**" and name it "Color" for example, the type make it "Single line of text"

[image]

2- Copy and paste the following formula :

```
=IF(OR(AND([SLA Day Counter]>3,AND(Initiative<>"Website-Full",Initiative<>"New Review",Initiative<>"Website-Other",Initiative<>"Website-Business",Initiative<>"Website-Update")),AND([SLA Day Counter]>10,OR(Initiative="Website-Full",Initiative="New Review",Initiative="Website-Other",Initiative="Website-Business",Initiative="Website-Update"))),"Red","Green")
```

3- Now check that column, it will write "Red" if the condition is true, else it will write "Green

4- Next step, format the "SLA Counter Day" Just like that :

[image]

---

### 1.3 Results

---

Here is the results I got :

[image]

---

### 2- Second Solution

---

Here, I am going to explain my second solution for your case following the Algebra logical expressions,

Let's name your following condition as follow :

- A = SLA Day Counter > 3
- B = Initiative != "Website-Full"
- C = Initiative != "New Review"
- D = Initiative != "Website-Other"
- E = Initiative != "Website-Business"
- F = Initiative != "Website-Update"
- X = SLA Day Counter > 10

So if we express your business need in a Mathematical format it will look like this :

(A && B && C && D && E && F) || (X && (B || C || D || E || F))

This is a little bit complicated and difficult to implement it directly to computer, so first we need to SIMPLIFY it using "**Boolean expression simplification**" Methods which called [Disjunctive normal form (DNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

**Results** : A && B && C && D && E && F || X

**Interpretation** :

[The SLA Day Counter > 3]
**AND**
Initiative != ["Website-Full","New Review", "Website-Business","Website-Other","Website-Update"]

**OR**

[The SLA Day Counter > 10]

So going to SharePoint, your solution will look like this :

[image]

And here is it, it gave me the same results :

[image]

**Please accept the answer if it works.**

Comment: OMGGGG IT WORKED. Thank you. You're amazing!!!

Comment: Wait!! This only works if I don't hide the colour column. Is there any way I can hide colour and still have the formatting?

Comment: Alright, I will come back to you when i figure out something it work !

Comment: @rilakkuma, check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Thank you for also taking the time to explain it :')

Comment: No problem, it was quite challenge and you made me remember old math days

Answer (score 2):

Give this format a try:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if((startsWith([$Initiative],'Website') && @currentField > 10) || (startsWith([$Initiative],'Website') == false && @currentField > 3),'red','')"
  }
}
```

Not sure what other format options you were going for, so this is pretty basic in that it just sets the `background-color` to red or nothing. I've simplified the logic a bit by using `startsWith` to make it easier to find those that begin with Website vs those that don't. I've also assumed you are applying this directly to the `SLA Day Counter` column so I've just used `@currentField` but if you are applying this elsewhere just swap those out with the `[$SLADayCounter]` (or whatever the internal name of the field is).

Comment: Hi there, I tried this but the SLA day counter goes red on website even if it's within the 10-day SLA. 

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPT7H.jpg

Comment: Did you paste the exact format I posted above? In your screenshot it looks like you are applying background classes to get that pink shade rather than just red. Here's the format above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbtKN.png

Comment: I just changed 'red' to the hex code #FABBC3 but otherwise, I used the exact format you suggested. I tried it just now with 'red' and I get the same result.